# MSSQL service fails to come up on vm restart

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a MS SQL 2008 R2 express installation on a VM. If the entire VM node reboots then the SQL service fails to come up. Restarting the VM in isolation results in running service. We have put the SQL service on delayed start and the actions for the service being stopped as restart for all counts of the service being stopped. The VM service supplied by openmindhosting.com they are secretive about when their VM node restarts - which suggests to me that the answer is to move hosts but in the short term is there a good monitoring application that somone can suggest (or some sequence of batches etc)?

Comment: It would be useful to know *why* the service fails to start... what does the event log say about it?

Comment: Its a hacking / dos attack that caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason for an attempted but failed MSSQL start will be in the MSSQL error log, as well as the system Event log.

Comment: Yes but that was not the question. I need to monitor the service and if it fails to run for any reason, try to recycle it.

Comment: I suggest you prevent people hacking a SQL system that should never be exposed to the outside, instead.

Comment: Once again, that was not the question (yes we have taken steps) and there was no full access to the database i.e. although one line of defence was cirumvented, another held. the site has been up for around 7 years without penetration.  Would people please confine their comments to the question.

Comment: can somone who has enought points, vote this answer down please?